# Batch - getting system info on console

Tags: batch-file, cmd, system

I want to know if there is a certain command that you can type into cmd to print system information, such as the RAM, hard drive storage, OS, etc. I have looked around but cannot find anything. If there is one, please give me the syntax and an example of using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) might be interesting for you.

E.g. `wmic cpu get Name` prints information about CPU

See: http://www.deepakg.com/blog/2007/08/using-wmic-for-gathering-system-info/, http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries.aspx and https://superuser.com/questions/334641/whats-the-equivalent-command-of-wmic-memlogical-in-windows-7

You could also use `systeminfo`

Comment: This is great, and I will most likely accept your answer when SO allows me to. Do you know just how many parts of the computer can be logged? And is there a syntax or is it different for each part? For example, is the CPU syntax the same as the OS syntax?

Comment: Are there any other websites that go into greater detail about this?

Comment: try `wmic /?` or google WMIC, it's quite powerful. Normally it's wmic SUBSYSTEM COMMAND PROPERTY

Comment: Thank you so much. In 2 minutes I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
start "" /w "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\msinfo\msinfo32.exe" /report "%temp%\msinfo.txt" /categories +all & more "%temp%\msinfo.txt"
```

Plus these are some other commands. Check the help on each `/?`.

```
nslookup -type=ANY www.smh.com.au

vssadmin list shadowstorage

winsat features -eef -v

SCHTASKS /query /fo:list

whoami

hostname

quser.exe

ipconfig

driverquery.exe /fo list

mrinfo

gpresult.exe

openfiles.exe

netstat

powercfg.exe

QUERY USER /server:myserver

tasklist
```